# Can I play video files included in html5 in Flask?

Tags: html, flask

i made a html5 files which has video file. Of course, this file works fine when it started works along.
But if you try to run it with a flask, it will not work.

I thought it was because of the file format so i used with avi, mp4, ogg... but problem doesn't solved

this is part of my HTML5 code

```
<body>
 <a href="/xxx">
  <video width=1000 height=500 loop autoplay>
   <source src="home/dgo/df/static/piano.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
   <source src="home/dgo/df/static/piano.mp4" type="video/avi"></source>
   <source src="home/dgo/df/static/piano.mp4" type="video/ogg"></source>
   <source src="home/dgo/df/static/piano.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
 </a>
</body>
```

this is part of my Flask code

```
@app.route('/')
def abc():
url_for('static', filename='cssfile.css')
return render_template('abc.HTML')
```

i don't know what is problem. please help me, i need your help guys:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your video files to static folder and update the paths in html

```
<source src="/static/piano.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

Comment: Thank you friend! I solved this problem with your advice.Have a nice day!!!